# How to edit terminal word boundary characters?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, dconf, gsettings

Highlighted text in the default gnome terminal incorrectly includes word boundary characters which should be ignored

for example when I double click on

```
 &freq_domain_magnitude_buffer_a2i
```

it should ignore the leading  `&` and just highlight `freq_domain_magnitude_buffer_a2i`

In the past below technique worked (it has no effect now) to define a set of such word boundary characters

```
UUID=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default |  tr -d "'" ) #  strip off any single quotes

echo $UUID

gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${UUID}/ word-char-exceptions  '@ms "-#%&+,./:=?@_~"'
```

Even back when above worked its troubling to see the word `legacy` ... How to edit the list of word boundary characters ? can this be done using tool `dconf-editor`  ?   Is there a better alternative terminal which does support defining word boundary characters ?

This issue goes back years

[dconf write word-char-exceptions not taking effect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868515/dconf-write-word-char-exceptions-not-taking-effect)

[Can I specify what characters set the double-click selection boundary in GNOME Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8413/can-i-specify-what-characters-set-the-double-click-selection-boundary-in-gnome-t)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409017/gnome-terminal-double-click-delimiters

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1165244

On Ubuntu 22.04 gnome terminal (Version 3.44.0 for GNOME 42)

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `gsettings get` prints its output within single quotes, i.e. the value of `UUID` doesn't become the actual UUID that you'd expect but rather that value enclosed in literal apostrophes. You should remove those apostrophes.

It's surely all doable via command line, using either `gsettings` (as you did) or `dconf`, and a bit of shell script gluing. However, I find it more convenient to navigate in `dconf-editor`. As you navigate to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:`, you'll probably see some of the subfolders already containing apostrophes in their names due to previous runs of the incorrect script that you posted. These are not used by `gnome-terminal`, you may right-click and "Reset recursively". If you navigate to the given correct profile's `word-char-exceptions`, you can see the old value or set the new value there.

PS. Don't worry about the word "legacy". I have no idea why it's there, but it's there, it's okay.

Comment: this is not an answer ... thanks anyhow

Comment: Why is this not an answer? Did you fix the problem with the apostrophe and it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes I updated question with code to strip off surrounding single quotes around UUID however that is not the root issue see updated question ... also did recursive reset using dconf-editor ... still fails to change word boundary characters

Comment: I see. I'm sorry but I probably won't be able to further help you out here. It works on my 22.04.